# Permissions help setting up user access to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Still new to AWS.  I'm trying to grant a user access to only S3 buckets that have a particular naming convention.  I've got a basic policy like so:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowActionsForProjectbucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["s3:*"],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-*/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-*"
        ]
    },
}
```

However I'm getting Access Denied errors when running.

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

I'm confused I guess by the error message, as I assumed that the s3:* Action covered the ListBuckets, but perhaps it's something else.

Comment: You get the access denied error when running what? You should be able to run "aws s3 ls s3://bucket-xyz" (a bucket that matches the policy) but not "aws s3 ls" (all buckets).

Answer (score 0):

Add below policy to your AWS IAM user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/05/grant-access-to-only-one-s3-bucket-to-aws-user.html